# Positive integer bigger then 2147483647 still throws InvalidArgumentException

Tags: php, integer

I've got the following value object `SeriesNumber` that is supposed to be able to contain any positive integer. But when I set the value to something bigger than 2147483647 the error is thrown, but this clearly is a positive integer?

How can I get rid of this limit or weird behavior so I can for example use 8750465442 or higher as the value for my series number?

```
namespace Model\Domain\User\Value;

use \InvalidArgumentException;

class SeriesNumber
{
    private $value;

    public function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->setValue($value);
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->value;
    }

    private function setValue($value)
    {
        if (!(is_int($value) && $value >= 1)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('%s must be a positive integer.', __METHOD__));
        }

        $this->value = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
C:\Users\Niet>php -r "var_dump(2147483647);"
int(2147483647)

C:\Users\Niet>php -r "var_dump(2147483648);"
float(2147483648)
```

Notice how the second one is *not* an integer, because it has gone beyond what can be saved in an integer. Therefore, `is_int` returns false.

To fix, consider using BCMath functions to handle arbitrarily large numbers.

Comment: But when I put it in a string I can use very large numbers. I think that would be a solution, but why is that?

Comment: @KidDiamond because a string is not a number. The number `2147483647` occupies 4 bytes, whereas the string `"2147483647"` occupies 11 bytes. In a string each character is represented by one [or more in UTF] characters, and the string itself is terminated by a `\0` or `NULL` byte. You can easily perform basic math operations on a number in-CPU, with a number represented as a string you need to load a special library designed to do such odd things, eg: BCmath.

Comment: @Sammitch PHP strings are not null-terminated. For proof of this, try `var_dump("\x00\x00\x00");` - you will get a string of length 3.

Comment: PHP is an interpreted language that lives on top of C, C strings are null-terminated.

Comment: @Sammitch Pretty sure PHP strings are handled as arrays of characters, actually.

Answer (score 1):

2147483647 is the largest possible signed 32-bit integer. If you want to represent larger numbers you need to run 64-bit PHP on a 64-bit machine.

Alternatively you could use the [BCmath](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) extension.

That said, you'll never be able to have a computer accurately store *any* positive integer. At the moment anything above 2^64 is probably best kept as a string.